# How to write bluetooth c program through Termux (Android root)

Tags: bluetooth, android-bluetooth, bluez, termux, hci

I'm trying to write a c program that uses `<bluetooth/bluetooth.h>` library  and exeute it in Termux.

I somehow managed to install the blueZ library straight from google git source files and I'm able to compile without errors my c program. The function `hci_get_route(NULL);` returns negative value which means there is no local bluetooth device (perror: `Address family not supported by protocol`). When I execute `sudo hcitool dev` it shows no device. I'm wondering if it would be easier to set dual boot in my phone and execute the c program through another OS. As far as I know Termux has no Bluetooth API. Any suggestion is welcomed :)

PD: I've also written in the Termux git forum but I got no answer within a week.

Comment: I don't think there is a solution if Termux does not offer any Bluetooth functionality. Is there a reason why you are taking this path instead of developing a native Android App?

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan I want to make a "shell-type" program in c, just like websploit. And execute it as a normal c program. I just want a linux terminal in my phone that can access the whole OS. Maybe dual boot is my best choice but I want to try to get it done on termux because it is so easy to open an app and have a terminal there u know